# Why parentCampaignId is not in scope inside onClick method?

Tags: javascript

In this method when I declare parentCampaignId above while loop, it is no longer accessible inside the onClick method. But if I declare inside the while I can access the variable inside onClick method. Why is that? Why is scope depends on the while loop?

I asked my colleagues and a senior. They don't know. I tried googling as well and did not find any solution.

```
getBreadcrumbs() {
      let breadCrumbStack = [];
      let parentCampaign = this.getParentCampaign(this.props.campaign.get('parent_id'));
      while(typeof parentCampaign !== 'undefined') {
          let parentCampaignId = parentCampaign.get('campaign_id');
          breadCrumbStack.unshift({
              onClick: (() => {
                  window.location.href = '/cd/campaign/manage/campaign/'+parentCampaignId;  # Since parentCampaignId declared inside while it is accessible
              }).bind(this),
              label: parentCampaign.get('name')
          });
          parentCampaign = this.getParentCampaign(parentCampaign.get('parent_id'));
      }
      return breadCrumbStack;
  }
```

```
getBreadcrumbs() {
      let breadCrumbStack = [];
      let parentCampaign = this.getParentCampaign(this.props.campaign.get('parent_id'));
      let parentCampaignId = parentCampaign.get('campaign_id');
      while(typeof parentCampaign !== 'undefined') {
          breadCrumbStack.unshift({
              onClick: (() => {
                  window.location.href = '/cd/campaign/manage/campaign/'+parentCampaignId;  # Now parentCampaignId declared outside while and it is no longer accessible
              }).bind(this),
              label: parentCampaign.get('name')
          });
          parentCampaign = this.getParentCampaign(parentCampaign.get('parent_id'));
      }
      return breadCrumbStack;
  }
```

I expected in both cases to be working but it is not working in the 2nd case (when parentCampaignId is declared outside while loop).

Comment: do you checked parentCampaign in console?

Comment: Try to think about why you need `parentCampaign = this.getParentCampaign(parentCampaign.get('parent_id'));` in the end of while loop.

Comment: Maybe `parentCampaign.get('campaign_id');` is not returning anything and the while loop is not running at all. And if `parentCampaignId` will get a value you will have an infinite while loop, because you don't change it's value.

Comment: @VadimHulevich Yeah I did. It is undefined.

Comment: @yip102011 To update the parentCampaign. Otherwise it will be an infinite loop

Comment: While loop is running. And at the end of loop I am updating the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onClick` you *define* a function, that function uses the variable
`parentCampaignId` which is not a local variable of this function.
Therefore JavaScript takes that variable and puts
it in a closure (*google* that :-) ) together with the function.
At the time the onClick function gets *executed* the
`window.location.href` is filled with the value that
the variable `parentCampaignId` has *at that time*.

Now, in your first example, each iteration creates a new `parentCampaignId`
variable (by the `let` keyword *inside* the loop), which then is contained in the closure.
It initially got the value you expected and never changes.
So this `onClick` works as you expected.

In the second example however, the `parentCampaignId` was created once,
outside the loop. That one and only `parentCampaignId` is contained in the
closure of each `onClick` function.
And at the time the `onClick` functions are executed
they all will have the same `parentCampaignId` variable, containing the
value it had at the return of `getBreadcrumbs()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. I guess your first `parentCampaignId` is empty and you didn't update `parentCampaignId` at the end of loop so the `parentCampaignId` stay empty forever and you thought that is not accessible.

May you use `console.log` to see what is the first `parentCampaignId`?